Too much space before and after \[\]
Whenever I use \[ ... \] in my LaTeX document, there is too much space before and after the equation. How can I fix this?

My crystal ball tells me that you might be having blank lines before \[ and after \]. Delete them. If not, then you'll have to show some code causing the issue, or wait for someone with a better crystal ball...

Please also tell us if you've modified the line-spacing settings. Depending on how you've increased overall interline spacing, the amounts of whitespace above and below displayed equations may look particularly excessive. As @campa has already encouraged you to do (implicitly...), please provide more and actionalble information about your document setup.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298124/why-does-latex-insert-space-before-formulas/298141#298141

@Mico Yeah, indeed a bit implicitly... in my defence I was on smartphone. Fluffy: please add a minimal working example which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.
